# Old questions refresh to meet new standards

Tags: discussion, editing, answer-quality, question-quality

This question is influenced by my question about [נשים פטורות ממצוות עשה](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/95096/how-womens-ptur-from-time-related-mitzvot-works), which was suggested as a dupe of [Why are women exempt from (many) time-bound mitzvot?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10540/why-are-women-exempt-from-many-time-bound-mitzvot)

When I saw the later question and the answers, they were incompatible with today's standards of quality (I'm often criticized for and I mostly accept that).

It seems that the site has to maintain its consistency, and measures should be taken to improve some old questions to meet the new standards (at least for the active users).

I would note that in my eyes the site transforms from a sort of Quora to J-Wiki and it should find a way to keep with that change.

Any thought in this direction?

Comment: I am still trying to understand what you find deficient in that question.  I don't think this is an old question getting a free pass because of age.  Absent specific feedback, it's hard for me to know what you're looking for.  In particular, you seem to be unhappy that I reported what I've heard, that contributed to my confusion and led me to ask the question, as if that's a bad thing.  We don't want people tossing out one-liners; we want them to provide context.

Comment: I wrote so much and even added an answer. tell me if you still don't understand what's the problem with your phrasing.

Answer (score 7):

This is a good issue to raise, and I think there is a simple approach to deal with the problem:

All questions and answers should ideally be as good as possible. Whether a question is old or new is not so relevant. If you see a post that is deficient, you can do any of the following:

- Downvote it
- Leave a comment expressing the problems
- Edit it to improve it
- Flag/vote to close if it falls under any of those categories

If you find questions that are lacking good answers, you can post your own answer or start a bounty to encourage others to post an answer. There is no statute of limitations on questions; you can  post new answers even if a question is 10 years old. Additionally, if you want input from other community members you can always start a discussion in [Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/vdibarta-bam).

Comment: There's also the "historical significance" lock